# Create a .php or .txt file with VB6

Tags: php, vb6

So I'm trying to finish up my website, but since it has a lot of pages I want to speed up the process.

Every post I make needs a .SQL file with the data that will later be used in the .php file to fill everything, now, what I want to do is fill out the info on a VB6 form so that it'll put the data on my database and create a .php file with the given text (that will include all html and php code as well as the variables for every specific post) or a .txt file so I can later just change its extension.

How could I do this?

I'm sorry if I didn't express myself well and thanks in advance, cheers!

EDIT: I know I could do it with just getting the data from my database and having a single dynamic php file, but trust me, for what I need it's better having different files.

Also yes, I meant by ".SQL file" that it'll be just a row in my database.

So basically what I need is to write a certain text on a .txt file (preferably save it with the .php extension) and also for the program to write the data on my database (I already did that part).

Again, sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: My god... what have you done?

Comment: What do you mean "every post needs a SQL and PHP file"?  Can't you just create a single generic page which reads posts from the database and displays them dynamically?

Comment: Wait, what? Are you storing data with .sql files? Why not use a database?

Comment: Why not code a PHP script that fit your needs instead of VB6 that generate a lot of PHP files?

Comment: As you've undoubtedly gathered from these comments, it's really not clear what you're trying to do or why.  What you describe sounds to us like a _very_ bad approach to whatever you're trying to do.  You might want to step back for a minute and describe the end goal a little more clearly here.

Comment: ... and also from what people can half gather it sounds painful.

Comment: Edited, hopefully you can understand better now ^^

Comment: @SebastianSalines: Your edit doesnt help. The problem is this is a horrible implementation with no explanation as to why youre using this horrible implementation. If you could give us more detail about what the actual end goal is in terms of requirements then we can give you a better implementation and explain it, but there no explaining what you have doen to this point because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do what you want is to create a form handler (which wont be visible). And the form handler will take your form data and instantiate it (create/update/delete) form the rows in your SQL DB.

Additionally you can upload the handler as required via your vb6 application and REMOVE it after your done with the updates to your SQL DB.

Also if you have more than row that you wish to create/update/delete, then you could recursively send the form data to your Form handler.

Pass your data in a generic HTML form which you ought ot be able to create dynamically on the fly using plain text.

This approach will work for strings and numbers but not for images which usually need to be chunked.

Once your handler has processed the request it can redirect you to a "Success.html" or "Failed.html" page so you know it if succeeded or not.

Pseudo code for `HANDLER.ASPX` or `HANDLER.PHP`:

```
If formdata is valid
  try
    create/update/delete row in SQDB
    redirect to success.html?action=create or update or delete
  catch
    redirect to failed.html?errorid=12345
  end try
else
  redirect to failed.html?errorid=12345
end if
```

HTML form script (you will generate this in vb6 in your vb code):

```
<form action="myhandler.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="recordId" value="123" />
    <input type="text" id="firstname" value="Bob" />
    <input type="text" id="lastname" value="Smith" />
    <input type="text" id="Street" value="123 high lane" />
    <input type="text" id="District" value="Moss Side" />
    <input type="text" id="City" value="Manchester" />
</form>
```